# Why "de" is used instead of "con" when saying that 'you're in love with someone'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, preposiciones

Why in the below sentence does it use "de la" instead of "con la"? Is there rule when to do so?

> Me han dicho que estás enamorado **de la** nueva secretaria.

That is:

> They told me that you're in love **with the** new secretary.

Comment: Prepositions are different in every language, you just have to learn them.  Never try to switch from one language to another directly, as it will not always work.

Comment: Actually, in English, *enamoured of* is preferred over *enamoured with*.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the verb, "enamorado", **the feeling is yours**, not hers.

When you say "de" the action is **from you to her**
- Me han dicho que estas enamorado de la nueva secretaria.
- They told me that you are in love (and the reason is her). The new secretary.

The action "enamorado" comes from you and is directed to her
The sentence doesn't say if she is in love too

When you say "con" the action **includes both**
 - Me han dicho que estas enamorado con la nueva secretaria.
 - They told me that you are in love... (but is she in love too?)

It is ambiguous, because in the first part, you say that you are in love, but in the second part you are saying she is with you in the same feeling.

Comment: As a native speaker, I'd never heard "enamorado con" used with people. Could you add some references?

Comment: @FGSUZ: Looks like a literal translation of the English form, but I think it should be enamorados con.

Comment: @Joshua and why do you think so?

Comment: @FGSUZ: because it only makes sense with a plural subject, so I think there's an implicit pronoun nosotros. Or in this case ustedes.

Comment: @Joshua Rather than having 2 subjects, it's involving 2 people. But I don't think that implies anything. Another synonym of "enamorarse" is "colgarse de" (colloquial), and that'd translate as "hang by someone". USing "by" would make more sense to me, like "being captured by someone". But the fact is that neither of them are used.

Comment: @FGSUZ *Enamorado con* is not idiomatic, so I see eye to eye with you on this one.

Comment: Oh okay haha. I thought you were trying to relate falling in love and looking eye to eye haha. I'm deleting my comments.

Comment: @FGSUZ As you must know, there is one way in which "con" can be used with "estar enamorados" (plural), but the "con"-phrase will tend to be used as a separate adverbial: ***Con** María estamos muy enamorados* (meaning: Maria and I are deeply in love with each other.)

Comment: Whoa, so true, I hadn't come up with that. But it has a different meaning anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I'll ask you the same question: Why does English use "with" instead of "of"? This shows that it is not a good idea to try to "fit" the Spanish language into the English rules.

This is just the "collocation". There are some structures that are just like that. For example, why do you say "depend on", and not "depend of"? or "depend in"? It's just teh collocation.

So you should highlight **enamorarse de**, and not **de la**, because the important part is the structure verb+preposition. There are just some verbs which **need** that proposition.

> Enamorarse DE
>
> Soñar CON
>
> Pensar EN
>
> ...

So, that's how it works. I know this is not very satisfying, but the most I can say is: "try to find a mnemonic device". It completely lacks of rigour, but it might help.

So, let's try to embellish this a little bit. RAE defines **enamorar(se)** as

> 3. prnl. Prendarse de amor de alguien.

and **prendarse** means

> 2. tr. Ganar la voluntad y agrado de alguien.

So now you might recognise that "of" can be suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike English, prepositions in Spanish do not work in the same way; sometimes they match.

We always collocate *enamorado de alguien*, but we do not say, *enamorado con alguien*, which sounds horrible to my ears.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that prepositions don't always match one-to-one between languages. But the problem here is not the preposition, but the translation of *enamorado*.

If you translate it with the much more literal *enamoured*, you see that the preposition used is really the same:

> Estoy enamorado de ella.
>
> I'm enamoured of her.

What we see here is just that the two languages express the same sentiment in slightly different ways and literal translations are often not the most idiomatic. (cf. *i'm hungry* vs. *tengo hambre*)

Comment: I do not think "enamoured by" is idiomatic English, at least where I live. Is it a regional usage?

Comment: well i'm not a native english speaker, looking it up it seems that "of" is used more often, and fits even better here.

Comment: Idiomatically speaking, *be in love* is how *estar enamorado* is interpreted, and I doubt that a native English speaker would use *enamoured* to show this meaning.

Comment: ***Enamored of someone*** is old fashioned. However, it does show the pronouns are the same for to be enamored of someone.  The idiomatic translation is:to be in love with someone.

Comment: yes, @Ustanak, that's what i'm saying.